# Is there any way to do event subscription in linux

Tags: linux, events

I have done event subscription in Windows, using windows API's. So the same event subscription I have to do in Linux. But I am not getting any data related to event subscription in Linux. Is actually Linux supports event subscription?

Comment: What do you mean by event?

Comment: Starting a new process , service or killing a process. Like this events